How to have different set of features when compiled as a binary and used as a library in a Rust project?
I have been developing a chess engine and I have published it in crates.io for public use.
Links:

https://crates.io/crates/timecat
https://github.com/Gourab-Ghosh/timecat-rs/

My chess engine has differnet features defined. But by default I don't want any of the features to be enabled in by default when it is used as a library. But when compiling it as a binary, I want the binary feature to be enabled.
Now if I add the binary feature in default features, while using it as a library I have to add it with the command cargo add timecat --no-default-features (Currently this is the state of my library)
If I don't add the binary feature in default features, while using it as a binary I have to install it with the command cargo install timecat --features binary
Both of them are not user friendly as many people do not read the documentation properly before using a crate.
What changes should I make in my code so that both cargo add timecat and cargo install timecat work as expected. (Please read the Cargo Features section in the README.md to know about each feature and then answer this question)
I have tried making virtual workspace and distributed the library part code in seperate filder and the binary part in another folder. It is compiling as a binary but I could not find a way to use it as a library. I tried to use it as a library by adding timecat = { path = "/path/to/timecat" }but chatgpt is suggesting me to make the path /path/to/timecat/timecat_lib which I don't want to do. Here is the link of my experimentation.
Link: https://github.com/Gourab-Ghosh/timecat-virtual-workspace-experimentation

I'd suggest you publish the library and binary from different packages: eg timecat-lib (with optional binary feature that's not enable by default) and timecat (that depends upon the above with the binary feature).  That said, it's curious to me that the library needs features enabled for it to work in a binary: perhaps you might want to revisit that design?

In a chess engine, even little gain of speed is significant. When someone is compiling it as a binary, they are most probably using some gui to play against it, they do not care about all the details like how much of the transposition table is filled up, How many times there are certain key collisions, etc, etc. So I have disabled some of these features to gain engine speed. i know that this gain in speed is really insignificant but I want to keep this idea in mind to disable some more features in future if needed. But these informations are definitely needed when it is used as an library.

Features should be additive (so that if a crate appears multiple times in the dependency graph, but with different features, they can be unified), so you should instead have a feature that enables the optional functionality; and such would probably not be enabled by default in most cases, with users only enabling them if desired?

Thankyou for your suggestion about features being additive. I should definitely consider that.
But this still doesn't solve the original problem. Let there is a feature called not_needed_in_binary. So in when using as a library I want to enable the feature and using as a binary, I want to disable the feature.
So the original problem comes to the question: How do I tell rust to use a different set of features when using as a library and another different set of features when using as a binary through code or Cargo.toml, and not through the terminal?

Per my first comment, create two distinct packages.

I have just realised today that there is a slight problem with this as well. When I publish a new version of my library, I want the binary to be the same vestion as the library to let my users know that the binary updated. And binary code will never need any update. Although technically it is possible, it doesn't sound like the optimal method, changing the version only without changing the code and publishing it again and again. And more importantly I do not want to publish a seperate package with only 10-15 lines of code unless extremely necessary. Isn't this possible by workspaces?

Workspaces encompass multiple packages, so one can make it easier to handle separate timecat and timecat-lib packages, but it doesn't let you do anything in terms of publishing that you couldn't already do without a workspace.

So is there any other solution to solve this without making two seperate packages for library and binary?

Thanks to  @eggyal for suggesting features being constructive. Previously if anyone added the binary feature, it would be a disaster because the feature was destructive. Even it was more idiotic of me to keep the functionalities in the code but it would do nothing calling them. Finally the features being constructive, the current state of the library features are not as disasterous as before. So adding binary feature when not used as a library is fine now.
